# How to aggregate DataFrame and drop duplicates based on values in two columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, aggregation

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

```
ID  | COL1| COL2 | COL3
----------|------|------
123 | XXX | 0    | 1
123 | XXX | 1    | 1
444 | ABC | 1    | 1
444 | ABC | 1    | 1 
555 | PPP | 0    | 0
```

And I need to drop duplicates in above DF in that way:

- if in COL2 or COL3 is at least once '1' then should be 1 in these columns for ID (nevermind how often he had 0 in mentioned columns)
- rest of columns should still be in output
- In COL1 the is no duplicates per ID

So as a result I need output like below (I have many more columns so in output I need to have not only ID, COL2, COL3, but ID, COL1, COL2, COL3)

```
ID  | COL1| COL2 | COL3
----|-----|------|-----
123 | XXX | 1    | 1
444 | ABC | 1    | 1
555 | PPP | 0    | 0
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```
out = df.groupby(['ID', 'COL1'], as_index=False).max()
```

output:

```
    ID COL1  COL2  COL3
0  123  XXX     1     1
1  444  ABC     1     1
2  555  PPP     0     0
```